# GAE Python Webapp2 auth token doesn't register user nor delete old tokens in production

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, authentication

I'm using webapp2 for user authentication of Google App Engine, based on this article: http://blog.abahgat.com/2013/01/07/user-authentication-with-webapp2-on-google-app-engine/

Locally through the SDK, everything works exactly as expected. However when I deploy to production, the entities under UserToken only have {} as value for user. Because of this I can't properly use the authentication tokens.

What could influence this? The website is only accessible through HTTPS, but I can't imagine that that is causing it. Any input would be very much appreciated!

EDIT:
Adding requested code.

User model

```
import webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from webapp2_extras import security

class User(webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models.User):
  def set_password(self, raw_password):
    """Sets the password for the current user

    :param raw_password:
        The raw password which will be hashed and stored
    """
    self.password = security.generate_password_hash(raw_password, length=12)

  @classmethod
  def get_by_auth_token(cls, user_id, token, subject='auth'):
    """Returns a user object based on a user ID and token.

    :param user_id:
        The user_id of the requesting user.
    :param token:
        The token string to be verified.
    :returns:
        A tuple ``(User, timestamp)``, with a user object and
        the token timestamp, or ``(None, None)`` if both were not found.
    """
    token_key = cls.token_model.get_key(user_id, subject, token)
    user_key = ndb.Key(cls, user_id)
    # Use get_multi() to save a RPC call.
    valid_token, user = ndb.get_multi([token_key, user_key])
    if valid_token and user:
        timestamp = int(time.mktime(valid_token.created.timetuple()))
        return user, timestamp

    return None, None
```

When creating the user, I use following code:

```
from webapp2_extras import sessions, auth
import webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models

unique_properties = ['email_address']
user_data = self.user_model.create_user(email, unique_properties,
      email_address=email, first_name=first_name, password_raw=password, verified=False)
```

The code that is then used to create a token for 'user' is:

```
user_id = user.get_id()
token = self.user_model.create_signup_token(user_id)
```

The problem I have exists in the signup process as well as e.g. the forgot password process. As far as I can see, this is where something goes wrong. Not sure what though.

I've checked to make sure that an id is actually passed, and it is. Funny enough, the keyname of the token does include the user id, however on production the user field is left empty. Working locally it does include the user field.

Comment: Can you show us the gist of your code (extended user model and how you build it up and save it)?  That article is long and there may be several things going wrong (and I don't find the screenshots in that article at all readable in terms of the details of the code...).

Comment: Sure Alex, I've added the code you requested. Thanks.

Comment: Would you have any ideas based on the code? I can't grasp why it registers the user field locally, but not on production...